# Looping: 10 text box controls to check if they exist in database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I have 10 textbox controls. In my database there are 3 columns, `ItemCode`, `Product`, and `Quantity`. I want to check if the `ItemCode` already exists, so every time the user inputs an existing `ItemCode`, only the `Quantity` will update.

Here's my code:

```
try
{
    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from TblInventory where ItemCode='" + txtItem.Text + "'");

    command.Connection = con;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", txtItem.Text);

    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())   // Update Item Code if already exit
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Update TblInventory set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE ItemCode = @itemcode");

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
        txtProduct.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", time);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("You added " + txtQuantity.Text + " " + txtProduct.Text, "Existing Item");
    }
}
```

But my problem is that I have 10 text box controls to check. Instead of declaring one by one. How can I make a loop that will allow the text boxes which is for the `ItemCode` to check whether they exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

Pull this entire processing logic in a method which accepts two parameter one for `Quantity` type `INT` and one for `itemcode` type `string`. Then for every new insert by user call this method passing those two textbox value accordingly (you will have to convert the textbox value to `INT` for quantity).

You may as well consider the method to return `INT` to let know how many record has been updated since anyways you are calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` which returns the same.

Comment: Do I need to declare the text boxes in an array?